# Proof involving images and pre-images of a function

Tags: functions, proof-explanation

Here is a problem from the Book of Book proof by Hammack.

*Consider a function $f:A \rightarrow B$ and a subset $X \subseteq A$. Prove $X \subseteq f^{-1}(f(X))$.*

The book lists the proof as follows (I broke it into lines):

1. Proof. Assume $f:A \rightarrow B$ and $X \subseteq A$.
2. Suppose $a \in X$.
3. Thus, $f(a) \in \{f(x): x \in X\} = f(X)$.  That is $f(a) \in f(X)$.
4. Then, $f^{-1}(f(X))=\{x \in A: f(x) \in f(X)\}$.
5. Hence, $a \in f^{-1}(f(X))$
6. This proves $X \subseteq f^{-1}(f(X))$.

Here are two definitions for image and pre-image that were employed:

1. Image: If $X \subseteq A$, $f(X) = \{f(x):x \in Y\} \subseteq B$.
2. Pre-image: If $Y \subseteq B$, $f^{-1}(Y) = \{x \in A: f(x) \in Y\} \subseteq A$

I am having trouble understanding how to justify substitutions in the set builder notation and how one step in the proof leads to the next. I also need to identify the "backwards steps" in the proof as well as the "forward steps".

Please help!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The statement “$X \subseteq f^{-1}(f(X))$” is equivalent to the statement “for all $a\in X$, $a\in f^{-1}(f(X))$”, that is to say, every element of $X$ is also an element of $f^{-1}(f(X))$.

Now, it is clear that we have to show that *if we are given any element (say $a\in X$), then necessarily $a$ also belongs to the set $f^{-1}(f(X)) = \{x\in A \colon f(x)\in f(X)\}$*, which means that $a$ has the property that $f(a)\in f(X)$. Now, let’s take a look at $f(X)$. $f(X) = \{f(x) \colon x\in X\}$ is the set containing all the possible images of elements of $X$, i.e., all the elements of $B$ that can be written as $f(x)$ for some $x\in X$. Now we just have to observe that $f(a)$ has this property, so $f(a)\in f(X)$ and the proof is completed.

Comment: Thank you for your nice, thorough answer!  But, what do mean when you say on two occasions, "has this property"?  I feel very moronic for having to drill down like this, but for some reason I seem not to be able to apply some earlier material from the Book of Proof on set theory.  I do understand that in set builder notations, it follows the format {expression: rule).  However, for some reason, I am not making the intuitive jump necessary when things get more involved than that earlier material, like in the case of this problem.

Comment: When I say that "$a$ has this property" I mean "$a$ satisfies what I have just said/what I am going to say". For example, "$a$ has the property that $f(a)\in f(X)$" what I really mean is that "$a$ is such that $f(a)\in f(X)$", or "$f(a)$ has this property" $\iff$ "$f(a)$ can be written as $f(x)$ for some $x\in X$", since $a$ is in $X$ and $f(a)$ can be written as $f(a)$.